# Word counter with pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a pyspark dataframe with three columns, user_id, follower_count, and tweet, where tweet is of string type.

First I need to do the following pre-processing steps:
- lowercase all text
- remove punctuation (and any other non-ascii characters)
- Tokenize words (split by ' ')

Then I need to aggregate these results across all tweet values:
- Find the number of times each word has occurred
- Sort by frequency
- Extract top-n words and their respective counts

I've found the following the following resource wordcount.py on GitHub; however, I don't understand what the code is doing; because of this, I'm having some difficulties adjusting it within my notebook.

https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/python/wordcount.py

```py
lines = spark.read.text(sys.argv[1]).rdd.map(lambda r: r[0])
counts = lines.flatMap(lambda x: x.split(' ')) \
              .map(lambda x: (x, 1)) \
              .reduceByKey(add)
output = counts.collect()
for (word, count) in output:
    print("%s: %i" % (word, count))
```

Edit 1: I don't think I made it explicit that I'm trying to apply this analysis to the column, tweet.

Edit 2: I changed the code above, inserting df.tweet as argument passed to first line of code and triggered an error. So I suppose columns cannot be passed into this workflow; and I'm not sure how to navigate around this.

```py
TypeError: Column is not iterable
```

I've added in some adjustments as recommended. Works like a charm! I wasn't aware that I could send user defined functions into the lambda function. Turned out to be an easy way to add this step into workflow.

```py
import re
def process_text(text):
  text = text.lower()
  text = re.sub(pattern='[^A-z ^\s]',repl='',string=text).split(' ')
  return [word for word in text if word != '']

process_text('hi 343')
>>>> ['hi']

count_rdd = df.select("tweet").rdd.flatMap(lambda x: process_text(x[0])) \
              .map(lambda x: (x, 1)).reduceByKey(lambda x,y: x+y)

count_rdd.collect()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure if the error is due to `for (word, count) in output:` or due to RDD operations on a column.

BUT, you can simply use:

#### For RDD style:

```
count_rdd = df.select("tweets").rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x[0].split(' ')) \
              .map(lambda x: (x, 1)).reduceByKey(lambda x,y: x+y)
```

What you are trying to do is RDD operations on a `pyspark.sql.column.Column` object. Above is a simple word count for all words in the column.

If you want to it on the column itself, you can do this using [explode()](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.explode):

#### For Column style:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

count_df = df.withColumn('word', F.explode(F.split(F.col('tweets'), ' ')))\
    .groupBy('word')\
    .count()\
    .sort('count', ascending=False)
```

You'll be able to use [`regexp_replace()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.regexp_replace) and [`lower()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.lower) from `pyspark.sql.functions` to do the preprocessing steps.

Comment: Many thanks, I ended up sending a user defined function where you used x[0].split() and it works great! One question - why is x[0] used? I would have thought that this only finds the first character in the tweet string..

Comment: When I call `rdd` on a dataframe, It gives back a `Row` object which is an absraction of a tuple. You can access the value which is a tuple at the first index.

Answer (score 4):

**1:RDD** style

```
  lines=spark.sparkContext.textFile("../data/book.txt")
wordcount=lines.flatMap(lambda x: x.split(' ')).map(lambda x: (x,1)).reduceByKey(lambda x,y:x+y)\
.map(lambda x: (x[1], x[0])).sortByKey(False).collect()


#for word in wordcount:    print(word[1],word[0])
for i in range(2):    print(wordcount[i][1],wordcount[i][0])
```

**2:Dataframe** style

```
  from pyspark.sql.functions import split,col,explode,count


dflines=spark.read.text("../data/book.txt")
dfwords=dflines.withColumn('words',split(col('value'),' '))\
.withColumn('word',explode(col('words')))\
.drop('value','words').groupBy('word').agg(count('word')\
 .alias('count')).orderBy('count',ascending=False).show(2)
```

**3:SQL** style

```
sqllines=dflines.createOrReplaceTempView('lines')

spark.sql("""select word, count(word) count from
(select explode(split(value,' '))  word from lines) words group by word order by count desc""").show(2)
```

Comment: Note for anyone using a variant of any of these: be very careful aliasing a column name to `count` as that's a reserved name and can cause some really obscure bugs.  Leverage `word_count` or some other non-reserved name to be safe.

Answer (score 0):

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as fn
df.filter(fn.col('value') !='').show(10, truncate= False)
df_new= df.select(fn.explode(fn.split(fn.col('value'), "\W+")).alias("words"))
df_new.show(10)
new_df= df_new.select(fn.lower(fn.col('words')).alias('word'))
new_df.show(10)
df_new.createOrReplaceTempView("table")
spark.sql("select words, count(words) word_count from table group by words order by word_count desc").show(10)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).